# How to get the first occurrence of a group of values with T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2019

Having a SQL Server DB table below how can I get the data related to the first occurrence of a series of values (TableA and TableB_S have UserId linked) - I need to get the first occurrence of the last series of `IsActive = 1` value (the 5th row in the table, 1000  |1        |  2022-02-18 10:23:01):

`TableB_S`

| UserId | IsActive | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 0 | 2021-10-11 13:23:00 |
| 1000 | 0 | 2021-11-11 15:23:12 |
| 1000 | 1 | 2021-11-10 12:23:32 |
| 1000 | 0 | 2022-01-02 09:23:56 |
| 1000 | 1 | 2022-02-18 10:23:01 |
| 1000 | 1 | 2022-02-22 13:23:12 |
| 1000 | 1 | 2022-03-23 18:23:13 |

The query below returns the data related to the last occorrence of the value `IsActive = 1`  (1000 | 1    | 2022-03-23 18:23:13)

```
select a.*, ca.UserId, ca.Date
from TableA a

cross apply (select top 1 s.UserId, s.Date 
            from TableB_S s where s.UserId = a.UserId
        order by s.Date desc) ca
```

How to get this data ?

```
| 1000   | 1         |  2022-02-18 10:23:01 |
```

Comment: Could you define "series". What happens if there is 0,0,0,111111 as the data of isActive, or only zeros, or only 1s?

Comment: Sorry, I had to be more specific. For series I mean a group of 1s (```IsActive =1```) values which usually occur continuously for a period of time. As per your example, 0,0,0,111111, if we assume they occurred in chronological order query should return the 4th and for only 1s the first ever occurrence. For all zeros it should not return any values as we need only the active users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic here is "for each user get the set of rows which start a series of 1's (ie, the previous row in date order for the user is a zero, or doesn't exist), then of that set get the highest date".

```sql
select   UserId, IsActive, max([Date])
from     (
            select   UserId, 
                     IsActive, 
                     [Date],
                     PriorActive =  lag(IsActive, 1, 0) 
                                    over 
                                    (
                                       partition by UserId 
                                       order by [Date] asc
                                    )
            from     #TableB_S
         ) t
where    t.IsActive = 1 
         and t.PriorActive = 0
group by UserId, IsActive
```